# Modeling temperature using a trigonometric function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> In the month of March, the temperature at the South Pole varies over the day in a periodic way that can be modeled approximately by a trigonometric function.
>   The highest temperature is about $-50°C$, and it is reached around $2$ p.m. The lowest temperature is about $-54°C$ and it is reached half a day apart from the highest temperature, at $2$ a.m.
>
> Find the formula of the trigonometric function that models the temperature $T$ in the South Pole in March $t$ hours after midnight. Define the function using radians.
>
> What is the temperature at $5$ p.m.? Round your answer, if necessary, to two decimal places.

**Steps I took:**

So right away I set out to find the *amplitude* and *midpoint* of the function and those came out to be:

*Amplitude: $2$*
The mid-line was $-52°C$.

I also knew that the period would be $\dfrac { 2\pi  }{ 24 } $ since it takes $12$ hours to get to the minimum temperature and another $12$ to get to complete the period.

*Now I am confused by which trigonometric function to use*. I know that cosine would start with the max temperature and sine would start with the lowest temperature but it isn't clear to me which one I should start with *since 24 hours could start from $2$ am or $2$ pm*.

Comment: If it is a question from Khan Academy (which I assume it to be based on your previous questions) a graph must have been given to you which can show at $t=0$ what is the temperature.

Comment: @DheerajKumar Yes, it is from Khan Academy. However, a graph was not given.

Comment: Yes sorry that was very careless of me - I'm deleting that comment as it is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either sine or cosine. As you probably know, $\sin x$ reaches its maximum when $x = \pi/2$ and $\cos x$ reaches its maximum when $x = 0$. The graph of the sine function is just the graph of the cosine function shifted to the right (or the left) by $\pi/2$.